# Navigation Property Not Evaluated EF Core

Tags: ef-core-2.0

I have an issue in EF Core where I am trying to get a related entity and all it's dependent structures, but am not having much success with it.

Currently, I have a query like this:

```
var user = new Guid(id);
var userCustAffs = _data.UserCustomerAffiliation.Include(x => x.Customer)
                     .ThenInclude(x => x.Brand).Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(user)).ToList();
var result =  userCustAffs.Select(p => p.Customer).ToList();
```

When I should be able to do something like this to simplify it (and remove unneccesary things being evaluated locally vs the db)

```
var user = new Guid(id);
var userCustAffs = _data.UserCustomerAffiliation.Include(x => x.Customer)
                               .ThenInclude(x => x.Brand).Where(x => x.UserId.Equals(user))
                               .Select(y => y.Customer).ToList();
```

However, when I do the latter query, I get an error that

```
The Include operation for navigation '[x].Customer.Brand' is unnecessary and was ignored 
because the navigation is not reachable in the final query results
```

However, Brand is very important, as it drives some of the properties off of the Customer model.  What is the proper way to restructure this query so that I get the results I want (e.g. Customer with its relevant Brand, limited by the userId affiliated on the UserCustomerAffiliation table).

I have seen a recommendation before to "start" the query from the Customer instead of UserCustomerAffiliation, but that seems contrary to every instinct I have from a DB optimization standpoint (and Customer does not have a navigation property back to UserCustomerAffiliation atm).

Comment: Contrary or not, it is what it is and there is nothing you can do. Starting from `Customer` is not a recommendation, but a *requirement* for `Include` / `ThenInclude` functionality - [Ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)

Comment: @IvanStoev is that true if you use explicit loading, as is detailed later in that document?  As for it being contrary, my experience in manual creation of queries is that you start with the smallest relevant dataset, as it reduces the amount of data you are joining, which is why starting with what could be a larger dataset feels weird

Comment: I'm not saying it's good. In fact I'm considering it being a limitation of the current implementation which probably will be fixed in some future version. But currently it's mandator in order to use eager loading, which is the easier way to bring the related data. Explicit loading, lazy loading, manual projection, AutoMapper projection etc. are the other options, with their pros and cons.

Comment: You are not using any data from  `UserCustomerAffiliation`. Why you need the join to it - for filtering? Even if you don't have navigation property, you could start the query from `Customer` and use `EXISTS` for filtering - nowadays CBO query optimizers will turn into `JOIN` anyways. e.g. something like  `_data.Customers.Include(…).ThenInclude(…).Where(c => _data.UserCustomerAffiliation.Any(x => x.Customer.Id == c.Id))` would produce easily the desired result. Just to make your life easier :)

Comment: @IvanStoev UserId is on UserCustomerAffiliation, which is what we are filtering by

Comment: Ok, saw the `Where` clause. Still my last suggestion applies - just add the `User` condition to `Any`, e.g. `Where(c => data.UserCustomerAffiliation.Any(x => x.UserId == user && x.CustomerId == c.Id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to why this happens this (after some research) is quite interesting and a good example of why knowing how EF Core works is important to using it.

Linq in general works on the idea of deferred execution.  To put it very simply, if I make a Linq statement on a particular line, it may not get evaluated or executed until the data is "needed."  Most of the time we shortcut this with .ToList() which forces immediate execution.  The general idea here is that sometimes datasets are not needed (say, if an exception occurs before it gets evaluated but after it would be 'loaded').

EF Core takes this one step further and ties the idea of deferred execution with database optimization.  If, for example, I get a subset of data from the database:

```
var result = _context.SomeTable.Where(x => x.name == "SomeValue");
```

But later all I care about is the size of the dataset:

```
return result.Count;
```

The DB call can be optimized to

```
select count(*) from SomeTable where name = "SomeValue";
```

instead of

```
select * from SomeTable where name = "SomeValue";
```

Similarly, the query I have above was being optimized away.  Because I chained the whole thing before it was evaluated, the EF Core optimizer threw away a table I needed.

The reason this works:

```
var user = new Guid(id);
var userCustAffs = _data.UserCustomerAffiliation.Include(x => x.Customer)
                                         .ThenInclude(x => x.Brand).Where(x => 
                                         x.UserId.Equals(user)).ToList();
var result =  userCustAffs.Select(p => p.Customer).ToList();
```

Is because I force execution of the query that is something like

```
Select u.*, c.*, b.* from usercustomeraffiliation u, 
        inner join Customer c  on u.customerid = c.id 
        inner join Brand b on c.brandid = c.id 
        where u.userid = 'userId';
```

And then strip out the customer object (and the brand object underneath it) in memory.  It would be more efficient to be able to generate a query like:

```
Select c.*, b.* from Customer c  on u.customerid = c.id 
        inner join Brand b on c.brandid = c.id 
        where c.id in (select u.customerid from usercustomeraffiliation u 
                              where u.userid = 'userId');
```

But, that gets optimized away.